# Is it good practice to extract common exception throwing logic into its own method?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, design-patterns

We have the following repeated in our codebase:

```
var isUpdateAllowed = await this.security.IsUpdateAllowedAsync(userId, postId);
if (!isUpdateAllowed)
{
    throw new UnauthorizedException(string.Format(
        "Not allowed to update post. User={0} Post={1}",
        userId,
        postId));
}
```

We've already had to change the exception type once, which involved changing it in many places, so it seems like repeating the above violates DRY.

One proposed solution is we extract the above check into its own method. It can exist alongside the existing `IsUpdateAllowedAsync` method. We can call it `AssertUpdateAllowedAsync`. The call-site then becomes:

```
await this.security.AssertUpdateAllowedAsync(userId, postId);
```

I'm personally torn: on one hand we get DRY, but on the other hand I can't remember seeing many methods, other than `Assert.` in MSTest, that use the above convention.

Comment: If the code really is the same everywhere, and if you believe that it will change the same when the code is maintained, I don't see any reason not to put that into a method.

Comment: This seems fine to me. Is your concern simply unfamiliarity with the pattern? eg "I can't remember seeing many methods, other than Assert. in MSTest, that use the above convention"? MSTest doesn't own the assert verb, and there are still valid contexts for it outside of testing.

Answer (score 0):

Anytime you find yourself replicating code, it's good practice to put that into a helper method. The biggest reason for this is as you've already seen - a refactor goes down much smoother when the code only needs to be changed in a single place, rather than many.

The reason you don't often see Assert methods is because throwing an exception is often done as part of the method, and *checking* for accessibility like permissions is done via a `bool`-returning check method. This is because throwing an exception is costly due to the collection of potentially useful debug information such as the current `StackTrace` - it is therefore most often undesirable in production code to throw exceptions short of an actual, honest and confirmed error occurring, and even then it's mostly to tell you what to go back and fix.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a good idea.

Code that throws exceptions is no different from any other code with respect to re-use, and in this case it certainly seems sensible.

If you are not keen on the name then how about `ThrowIfUpdateNotAllowedAsync` or `CheckUpdateAllowedAsync`, although I kind of prefer the name that you have already chosen.

The biggest criticism with refactoring this logic into a method is that you are using exceptions for control flow - while refactoring into a separate method is simple, straightforward step in the right direction, I'd probably be looking at whether I could refactor to avoid throwing this exception entirely.

Answer (score -1):

Of course it is good practice to do so. 
I would add, though, not to make your assert method asynchronous. There's no point to that.